# Generate Tiles with GDAL

Tags: openlayers-3, gdal

I want to generate different raster according to scale like Google Maps with gdal tool **[GDAL2TILES](http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html)** for my WEB GIS who run with OL3. For example,
**scale 1 :** [image]
and the same place **Scale 2** : [image]

Comment: I think this is not an OpenLayers question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a tile server to seeding the tiles for your openlayers application to consume. And the different image output at different zoom level in the same location is called raster pyramid.

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Raster_pyramids

Back to your question, if you want to generate tiles, there are multiple solutions out there, many free open sourced ones are build based on GDAL as you mentioned such as GeoWebCache, MapProxy, etc.

You can seed/replace tile image at different zoom level to generate your own raster pyramids. And then you can either consume the Tile map service, or directly access the tiles via OpenLayers.